# Aurelia Dialog and Handling Button Events

Tags: aurelia

I have set up the aurelia-dialog plugin. It's working using the example in the GitHub readme, but the documentation doesn't explain anything about how to use it otherwise. I have a simple use case with a list page. I want to click an "add new" button, pop the modal dialog which has it's own VM. The modal contains a simple dropdown list. I need to select an item on the list and make an API call to save the data, but I can't seem to figure out how to wire up my save method with the save button on the dialog.

The method that opens the dialog on my list page (which works just fine):

```
loadAgencyDialog(id){
    this.dialogService.open({ viewModel: AddAgency, model: { id: id }}).then((result) => {
      if (!result.wasCancelled) {
        console.log('good');
        console.log(result.output);
      } else {
        console.log('bad');
      }
    });
```

My modal add-agency.js (VM for the modal, also loads the select list just fine and yes, I have a variable named kase because case is reserved):

```
import {DialogController} from 'aurelia-dialog';
import {ApiClient} from 'lib/api-client';
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(DialogController, apiClient)
export class AddAgency {
  kase = { id: '' };
  constructor(controller, apiClient){
    this.controller = controller;
    this.agencies = [];
    this.apiClient = apiClient;
  }

  activate(kase){
    this.kase = kase;
    this.apiClient.get('agencies')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(agencies => this.agencies = agencies.data)
      .then(() => console.log(this.agencies)); //these load fine
  }

  addAgency() {
      //Do API call to save the agency here, but how?
  }
}
```

This is part I'm unsure about. In the example, they use controller.ok(theobjectpassedin), which returns a promise. **But I don't get where I can call my addAgency method. Any ideas?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible I'm misunderstanding your question, but you should be able to just call `addAgency()` in your HTML:

`<button click.trigger="addAgency()">Add</button>`

And then do what you need to do in `addAgency()`, finishing with a call to `this.controller.ok()` to wrap up the modal.

As an example, here's my modal's `dialog-footer`:

```
<ai-dialog-footer>
  <button click.trigger="controller.cancel()">Cancel</button>
  <button click.trigger="ok(item)">Save</button>
</ai-dialog-footer>
```

And in my code:

```
ok(item) {
    this.controller.ok(item);
}
```

Not too complex. Hope that helps.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought too, but I have an object that I'm loading on the activate call in the modal. It gets a list of objects (agencies) and assigns them to a local variable (this.agencies). If I call my addAgency() method on the button, my this.agecies is always null. It's like after the activate method is called, my agencies object is whipped out.

Comment: That definitely helps and confirms that I was on the right path. Now I just need to find out why my this.agencies is always null after calling activate. But, you did answer the original question. Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to `return` your promise in the `activate()`, like `return this.apiClient.get('agencies') .then()....` ?

Comment: Yeah, that's normally what I do and I tried that too, but still, after activate, this.agencies is still null. Really strange.

Comment: @DonFitz - try using "that" instead of "this" after you get the JSON response - `var that = this; ... .then(agencies => that.agencies = agencies.data)`