# Aurelia Dialog not returning response after using dropdown

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-dialog

I'm using the aurelia-dialog plugin to allow users to generate a set of objects, and want the dialog's response to return the chosen objects.

The workflow is that the list of options is generated from an API call using a promise when the activate() method is called on the dialog.  The options are then displayed to the user, and selected from a dropdown.  The user then clicks ok and the response should be sent back. Here is the code that is supposed to accomplish it:

```
this.ds.open({
  viewModel: MyModal,
  model: {
    "title": "Select Objects",
    "message": "I hate this modal"
  }
}).then(response => {
  console.log("closed modal");
  console.log(response);

  if (!response.wasCancelled) {
    console.log('OK');
  } else {
    console.log('cancelled');
  }
  console.log(response.output);
});
```

And then in the modal.js:

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {DialogController} from 'aurelia-dialog';
import {ModalAPI} from './../apis/modal-api';

//@inject(ModalAPI, DialogController)
export class MyModal {
  static inject = [DialogController, ModalAPI];

  constructor(controller, api){
    this.controller = controller;
    this.api = api;

    controller.settings.centerHorizontalOnly = true;
  }

  activate(args){
    this.title = args.title;
    this.message = args.message;
    this.returnedSet = null;
    this.historicSetName = null;
    this.reportHist = null;


    return this.api.getReportHistory().then(reports => {
      this.reportHist = reports;
    });
  }

  selectHistoricReport() {
    console.log(this.historicSetName);
    if(this.historicSetName == "Select a report...") {
        this.returnedSet = null;
    } else {
        var selectedReport = this.reportHist.filter(x => x.name == this.historicSetName)[0];
        this.returnedSet = selectedReport.rsids;
    }
    console.log(this.returnedSet);
  }

  ok(returnedSet) {
    console.log(returnedSet);
    this.controller.ok(returnedSet);
  }
}
```

And then the html:

```
<template>
  <require from="../css/upload-set.css"></require>
  <ai-dialog class="selector panel panel-primary">
    <ai-dialog-header class="panel-heading">
    <button type="button" class="close" click.trigger="controller.cancel()" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">${title}</h4>
    </ai-dialog-header>
        <ai-dialog-body class="panel-body container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <label>Report: </label>
          <select value.bind="historicSetName" change.delegate="selectHistoricReport()" class="input-md form-control">
            <option ref="historicSetPlaceholder">Select a report...</option>
            <option repeat.for="historicReport of reportHist">${historicReport.name}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
        </ai-dialog-body>
        <ai-dialog-footer>
            <button click.trigger="controller.cancel()">Cancel</button>
            <button click.trigger="ok(returnedSet)">Save</button>
        </ai-dialog-footer>
    </ai-dialog>
</template>
```

As long as I don't touch the dropdown, the dialog will return a null (or any other value I initialize returnedSet to).  However, as soon as I click on the dropdown, clicking either the Save or Cancel button leads to nothing being returned and the console.log lines at the end of my first code block just get skipped.  I also tried removing the click.delegate line from my HTML, but that didn't change anything.

Anyone have any idea why this might be happening?
Also, I found this post([Aurelia Dialog and Handling Button Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34408914/aurelia-dialog-and-handling-button-events)) with an extremely similar problem, but can't seem to find any solution in there as to what I should do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if you change `this.controller.ok(returnedSet);` to `this.controller.ok(this.returnedSet);`? Any difference?

Comment: I don't get any difference, but thatnks for the suggestion.  I also tried `click.trigger="controller.ok(returnedSet)"` in my html to just skip using the js file altogether.  That doesn't seem to work either.